# Create element and append value of input

Tags: jquery, append, keyup

I'm trying to create an element(div) on keyup of the space key (key-code 32). And also append the value of input as text in the new created div. This is what I have so far:

```
$(input).live('keyup', function(e){

  if (e.keyCode == 32) {

var q = $(input).val();
var div = $('<div/>');

    div.append(q);

  }

});
```

It doesn't work. Here is an example: [JsBin](http://jsbin.com/utudow/edit#javascript,html,live)

Comment: You must also append `div` element to anywhere else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have fixed it for you
http://jsbin.com/uyagak/2

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
 $('input').live('keyup', function(e){

 if (e.keyCode == 32) {  
    var q = $('input').val();
    var div = $('<div/>');

    div.append(q);

    $('body').append(div);
 }
});
```